# Setting {reactive: false} causes {{#each}} to break?

Tags: meteor

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how something is supposed to work but whenever I set reactive to false it seems to break {{#each}} loops in my template.

I can recreate the issue with a simple example by creating a new meteor application, leaving autopublish etc intact and then the following code:

.js file:

```
Numbers = new Mongo.Collection('numbers');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.helpers({
    number: function() {
      return Numbers.find({},{reactive:false});
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Numbers.find().count() === 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        Numbers.insert({number: i});
    }
  });
}
```

.html file

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
  {{>hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    {{#each number}}
      {{this.number}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

In the instance above, nothing is printed. If I delete {reactive: false} then the numbers are printed as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code cannot work ; this is not what the `{reactive: false}` is made for. It would make sense for the subscribtion.

What happens here are the following steps :

- The application starts
- The template is rendered and go for the `Numbers helpers` which returns nothing because it did not received anything from the server yet
- And... that's it

What you want to see happen :

- The application starts
- The template is rendered and go for the `Numbers helpers` which returns nothing because it did not received anything from the server yet
- Because you did not add the `{reactive: false}` option, each time something is received from the server, the computation is replayed and the template is updated

If you add something that will trigger the computation, it will work :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('numbers');
  Template.hello.helpers({
    number: function() {
      var n = Numbers.find().fetch();
      return Numbers.find({},{reactive:false}).fetch();
    }
  });
}
```

It works now because the `var n = Numbers.find().fetch();` will trigger when the Numbers.find() cursor will change.

But it does not make much sense. Tell me what you want to achieve.

(I bet, that what you really want to do is more something like that : `Meteor.subscribe('numbers', {reactive:false});` and let the helper be reactive.

I made you a quick meteor pad to play with that : http://meteorpad.com/pad/4zJTtdLnWcWXLuEuj/collection_reactivity

Comment: Thanks fabien, that makes sense as to why nothing appears. I thought {reactive: false} was only an option on .find(), I can't see any reference to it with regard to subscriptions? My end goal is that I have a list ordered by votes. I don't want the order to change nor for items in the list to be added/removed until the page is manually refreshed.

Comment: So, you have to make the subscribe non reactive, kill it and remake it when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Hey @fabien, how do we do that " make the subscribe non reactive, kill it and remake it when the page is reloaded"